# can't load windows duall of ubuntu

Tags: windows, resume

I have installed ubuntu dually with windows.
now I can't load windows and I receive the bellow message:

the last attempt to resume the system from its previous location failed. attempt to resume again?

If anyone has handled this issue, please let me know.